# How to package my classes in a .jar, and still package as a war?

Tags: java, spring, maven

So I have a spring mvc web application that I built in IntelliJ 9, using maven.

When I run a:

```
mvn clean install
```

It packages everything up in both a .war file and an exploded war.

My project layout is using a maven simple web app arch type.

```
How can I have my classes compiled into a .jar file also?
```

Currently my classes are in:

```
/target/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/
```

What I want is for it to compile my code in .jar like:

```
myapp-1.0.jar
```

And that have this in my `/target/myapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder like all my other jars.

**Update**

**I want this done via maven, not intellij specific.**

Comment: So what's the problem with having the classes of the project in WEB-INF/classes instead as a jar in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: For one, some (testing) engineers often forget to update classes when you tell them to upgrade their installed webapp with the new code (so keeping the config). It's easier to have all code in the lib directory.

Comment: @Blankman I read your questions on SO about obfuscating web application. Can you provide the process you followed or some configuration files? I am able to generate an obfuscated jar and a war(without obfuscation). But I want to generate a war with obf. jar in it.

Comment: I have a use case which requires this kind of thing - My web app has a set of property files with different configurations for staging and production setup (e.g. a different database schema name). Everytime I deploy a war on my staging, I have to manually go and edit those files since the configurations committed in my repository are of production. If I have only java-code changes (which is mostly the case for me), it makes sense to deploy only the jar instead of deploying the entire war (and having to manually edit again) as I don't think deploying individual ".class" files is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create two artifacts - a JAR and a WAR.

I'm not sure what the advantage is of having your .class files in a JAR as opposed to WEB-INF/classes.  Both are compressed; the JAR won't provide an extra compression.  You might want to be re-using those .class files in other applications.  if that's the case, you might consider moving those Java classes into a separate module and adding the JAR file you create just as you would any other 3rd party JAR in your WAR file.  Other applications would easily be able to check out the JAR file from your repository and simply reuse it.  This arrangement is best done by moving the shared Java classes into a separate repository in your version control system.

Comment: i'm doing it because running proguard requires it apparently.

Comment: Well I want to do this using maven, so I can build w/o intellij.

Comment: As duffymo said, creating two Maven artifacts is the way to go: A jar artifact, containing the classes, and a war artifact, with a dependency to the jar artifact. Note that the dependencies of your classes need to be moved from the war project's pom.xml to the jar project.

Comment: I'd recommend using IntelliJ and ditching Maven.  Just my preference, of course.

Comment: I didn't say create two Maven artifacts.  I don't use Maven, and I don't recommend it at all.  Two separate artifacts can be accomplished with or without Maven.  I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is in the configuration for the war-plugin:

```
<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
```

which will do the job and create a separate jar file. This jar has a classifier "classes" which can be changed by giving into the configuration. This can be useful if you have separated integration-tests which rely on classed from the war project to publish them and make them available as dependencies. This has nothing to do with separation of responsibilities.

Comment: If you really want to have a separate jar and create a separate war file which contains the jar (WEB-INF/lib) you have to make separated projects one with the jar and one with the war code which has a dependency to the jar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me what benefit there could possibly be to having a WAR's contents packaged as a JAR. The code that implements the webapp won't work without the context that a WAR is deployed into.

That said, it's entirely practical to think in terms of extracting the functional core of your code into a separate Maven module that has JAR packaging and a nice Java API. Then your WAR module can be made to depend on that, and only needs to contain exactly the code to turn that Java API into a web-based API. This has the advantage that it will also greatly improve the ability of your code to be tested (testing against the JAR will definitely be easier) and allow you to think in terms of having other clients of the same underlying code. That might or might not interest you. Would you need *any* Java code directly in the WAR? Maybe, maybe not. There are several ways to do it after all…

Comment: Making a JAR and a WAR from the _same_ Maven module is just a bad idea. Don't do it. Think cleaner separation of responsibilities.

Answer (score -1):

Runninng

```
mvn jar:jar install
```

will make jar as if you have set packaging type to jar. Without any changes to your pom.

So all you need is to run that line separately, add it to the script or add `jar:jar` goal to your existing maven build.

Answer (score -2):

The packaging type is specified by the "packaging" tag in the pom.xml (usually placed quite on top of the file, together with the artifact id, version etc of the project.

Try to locate

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

in the pom.xml and change it to

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Answer (score -2):

ok write a java command in your console

jar cvf myapp-1.0.jar *.class

Comment: Did you hear about Maven ? Read the question carefully!